# Changing the plot position of z-axis

Tags: matlab, position, z-axis

I wanted to change the position of z-axis in a 3d graph. I tried to do using graph properties but it does not work, Matlab has this option in 2D plot in axis properties window in the graph, but it does not work in 3d plots. Currently,the plot is at z=0 and I wanted to the position to z=6. Attached is the sketch where I need to change the position of the curve plot (red) from z=0 to z6. I appreciate if there is any solution/suggestion regarding this issue. Thank you.

[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nyCX.png)

Regards,
Alishah

Comment: You can use the `plot3` function specifying the desired (constant) `z` values

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution for this question is that convert `z` in your formula to `z-6`. You know it from mathematics, It will shift a curve, 6 unit .

If you want to change in right or left, you plus or minus.